# Forcing Visual Studios 2017 to compile and run Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently using visual studios and love the IDE. The problem is that the main language is Java. I've been using this batch file as an external tool for compiling and running.

```
del Output /S /Q
mkdir Output
javac *.java -d Output
cd Output
java Main
```

The problem is it only allows one program at a time and this makes things hard. Is there any way to adapt this so that is gets the filename of the .java file and compiles that.

***Solved: the new code is:

```
del Output /S /Q
mkdir Output
javac %1.java -d Output
cd Output
java %1
```

Then I set the argument to be the file name.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. How do I make the code show up as such.

Comment: Don't force Visual Studio to compile and run Java. Use a Java IDE. Microsoft used to make one. There was a lawsuit. Microsoft does not ***do*** Java these days. And you surround the code with `\`\`` **or** put it on a newline, highlight it and press ctrl-k (which will indent it four spaces).

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party visual studio extension which allow you to use java in visual studio

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.JavaLanguageSupport

Comment: I've used that, I've gotten error after error to no avail.